# Refunding partial order, but refund confirmation email shows all ordered items

Tags: creditmemo, refund, ce-1.9.2.4

I use magento 1.9.2.4.

My customer wants to cancel part of her order before shipping.

So I created credit memo from the invoice, made partial refund. Afterwards, I sent the shipment email.

The shipment email shows only the item which was shipped.

However, the refund confirmation email shows all items which were ordered.

How this can show only the actually refunded item?

Comment: what is your magento version?? Please maintion

Comment: I use magento 1.9.2.4